# Least number of charts to describe a given manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gn.general-topology, smooth-manifolds

Hello,  I'm wondering if there is a standard reference discussing the least number of charts in an atlas of a given manifold required to describe it.

E.g. a circle requires at least two charts, and so on (I couldn't manage to get anything relevant neither on wikipedia nor on google, so I guess I'm lacking the correct terminology).

*Edit*: in the case of an open covering of a topological space by n+1 contractible sets (in that space) then n is called the Lusternik-Schnirelman Category of the space, see Andy Putman's answer.  The following book seems to be the standard reference http://books.google.fr/books?id=vMREfNN-L4gC&pg=PP1

Great, now I'm still interested by the initial question: does anybody know of another theory without this contractibility assumption (hoping that it allows more freedom)? e.g. would it lead to different numbers say for genus-g surfaces?

*Final edit*: yes different numbers for genus-g surfaces (see answers below), but not sure there is a theory without contractibility.   Right, really lots of interesting literature on the LS category nevertheless, hence the accepted answer.  For example there are estimates for non-simply connected compact simple Lie groups like PU(n) and SO(n) in Topology and its Applications, Volume 150, Issues 1-3, 14 May 2005, Pages 111-123.

Comment: Let $X$ be the manifold in question, would $\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\,\inf\{\#G: \, G\subseteq \pi_n(X)\, <G>=\pi_n(X)\}$ upper-bound the number of charts?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not quite the same thing, but a related object is the Lyusternik–Schnirelmann category of a topological space.  See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyusternik-Schnirelmann_category

Comment: Is there some reason this has the same name as the "category" that has objects and morphisms, or is this purely a case of the same English word getting used for two mathematical objects?

Comment: The concepts are unrelated.  The notion of the L-S category predated the "category-theoretic" notion of a category.  I suspect that its inspiration comes from the Baire category theorem.

Answer (score 20):

To answer your last question, the least number of charts needed to cover any orientable 2-manifold is 2.  Consider the usual embedding of an orientable surface Σ in R<sup>3</sup> which is symmetric across the plane z = 0 (as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus_(mathematics))), and let ε > 0 be sufficiently small.  The open subsets Σ ∩ {z > -ε}, Σ ∩ {z < ε} form a covering of Σ by charts: by Morse theory Σ ∩ {z > -ε} is diffeomorphic to Σ ∩ {z > ε}, which is diffeomorphic to an open subset of R<sup>2</sup> by projecting onto the xy-plane.

Comment: Note that the two open sets in Reid's answer may not be made contractible in general.  Indeed, for orientable 2-manifolds, 3 contractible sets are required, except for S^2, where 2 are required.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out after asking, so really the LS category measures something different, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I do not know if the following exactly answers your question.

I have found on the second page of Michor "Topics in Differential Geometry":
"Note finally that any manifold $M$ admits a finite atlas consisting of $\dim{M}+1$ not connected charts. This is a consequence of topological dimension theory [cf. Nagata, Modern Dimension Theory]; a proof for manifolds may be found in [cf. Greub, Halperin, Vanstone, Connections, curvature and cohomology.I]."

I hope to have been useful.

Comment: Yes, sounds like interesting references, and the result is intuitively satisfying, thanks! I'll try to find a library that has them...

Comment: Not connected charts?  What does this mean and if the charts are disconnected why can't we just view them a single disconnected chart i.e.: $\phi: \bigsqcup \mathbb{R}^{\dim(M)}\hookrightarrow M$ (assuming this is what is meant by a disconnected chart).

Answer (score 12):

After "dimension" this is the most basic numerical invariant of a manifold and the least explored. I found this reference some years ago: I. Bernstein, "On Imbedding Numbers of Differentiable Manifolds", Topology, Vol. 7, pp. 95-109.

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing out this reference! Mike Hopkins has also written on this concept: http://www.springerlink.com.ezproxy.webfeat.lib.ed.ac.uk/content/10nn3m243278717l/ In particular I think he answers the OP's question for (almost) all projective spaces.

Answer (score 7):

Orthogonal question: Does the (minimum) number of  charts needed to describe a manifold tell you anything about the manifold?

Comment: Is this appropriate as an answer? I would have commented on the question if I had the rep.

Comment: For the L-S category, having an upper bound on the category can bound the complexity of your manifold (e.g. in terms of cohomology) from above

Comment: The L-S category gives a lower bound on the number of critical points of a functional on your manifold.  That's the big abstract theorem that Lusternik and Schnirelmann proved.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that [Cech cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cech_cohomology) could yield the sort of answer you're looking for (at least in the contractible case).  The general idea is that it computes cohomology based on nothing but the so-called "incidence data" of a good cover (that is, which n-fold intersections of open sets in the cover are nonempty) -- in fact, a n-chain is nothing more than a formal sum of (nonempty) (n+1)-fold intersections, with **R** coefficients.  Of course, this cohomology theory is usually isomorphic to singular cohomology, de Rham cohomology, et al. (in particular, they agree in the case of manifolds).  So if your manifold has a high h<sup>1</sup>=rank(H<sup>1</sup>), for example, then there *must* be lots of different 2-fold intersections to generate H<sup>1</sup>, and also if your manifold has nonzero H<sup>k</sup> then there must exist a (k+1)-fold intersection of sets in the open cover, which means that you must have at least that many sets in *any* good cover.  (Note that if M is a k-dimensional orientable manifold, then H<sup>k</sup>(M)=**R** by Poincare duality.)

Comment: Cech cohomology is too weak to give a full answer, though, because it only gives you a bound on how to cover a space such that _all_ nonempty intersections are contractible, rather than just the individual open sets themselves.  For example, a sphere S^n can be covered by 2 contractible sets, even though it takes n+1 to give a good cover.  Also, you could have an acyclic space where you see no cohomological obstructions to the space itself being contractible, but \pi_1 is nonzero so you certainly need at least two contractible sets to cover.

Comment: Right.  (I also just realized that my last statement is clearly false; e.g., the unit disk has trivial cohomology.)  But maybe there's a weaker Cech-ish cohomology that can address this anyways.  What happens if we work with a complex where only the individual open sets must be contractible?  It seems possible that there's a statement along the lines of "the cohomology of this complex injects into the cohomology of a good cover", and maybe we could get a lower bound on the difference in rank (based on higher-dimensional cohomology of M and/or the cohomology of the nonempty intersections...?).